# I can't find out AMQP in sts(IDE)

Tags: macos, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to make sample of rabbitmq.
So I tried to make a project including "AMQP in I/O" in STS.
But I couldn't do that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a this solution.
maybe, It seems that AMPQ in I/O turned into RabbitMQ in Integration